# How Can I Upload Image Very Fast in PHP...?

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload multiple images using PHP. I've already made some code but it's very slow. So would like to make it faster. Any suggestion ?

Here is my code :

```
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
{ 
    $file_name =$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152)
    {
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }
    $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"upload/$rand$file_name");   
    if($moveResult) 
    {
        echo "</br>";
    } 
    else  
    {
        echo "error upload"; 
    }//endd upload   
}//end for foreach
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code that looks particularly slow. Maybe it's just the file upload speed that takes a while? There isn't much you can do about that.

Comment: Do you have a fast internet connection? How slow is slow? 5 seconds, 5 minutes?

Comment: How much during the upload process? What's the size of images you upload?

Comment: Have you tried to resize your biggest images?

Comment: The only thing slowing this down is the file size and your upload speed. Nothing here that would make it very slow. also, nothing seems to be setting $rand

Answer (score 3):

This is kinda the minimal code for uploading a file and the only thing that can slow it down is your internet connection. Although you can use jquery or javascript file upload plugins like http://fineuploader.com/. The advantages according to what you want is:

- Multiple file upload
- Callback functions: so that you can calculate the upload speed and see if it's really slow or not
  plus it's got many more benefits and features